# Find string in file, find file with same name and move

Tags: powershell

Hi I am wondering if someone can help me please.  I am trying to search through a list of xml files that contain a certain string.  From that if the file contains that string I want to obtain the WAV file name (normally also the same name as the xml file that contains the string) and move that WAV file to a folder.  There is also a further string in that same XML file which has the WAV file name if it is easier:

```
<ContentItem Href="./200149.wav">
```

I currently have the following to identify the string in the file - however it moves the XML file only.  I need it to also locate the WAV file and move that to another folder also.  Any ideas on how I can amend it to pick up the WAV file?

```
$Path = "FULL PATH NAME TO WHERE FILES ARE LOCATED"
$Text = 'STRING I AM SEARCHING FOR'
$PathArray = @()
$Destination = "FULL PATH NAME TO WHERE FILES ARE TO BE MOVED"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.xml" -Recurse | 
   Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
      ForEach-Object { 
         If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
            $PathArray += $_.FullName
            Move-Item -path $_.FullName -destination $Destination
         }
      }
```

Thanks All!

Comment: You said that normally the name of the files are the same? Well, in that case, if you find that .xml file, then you can replace the '.xml' extension with '.wav' extension and copy that file as well.
$wavFileSameName = ($_.FullName -split '\.')[0] + '.wav'
Move-Item -path $wavFileSameName -destination $Destination

Comment: Thank you for that I think that is what I was looking for :)